# Extensión para Chrome que muestre la url de la página actual

Tags: javascript, extensión-google-chrome, chrome

estoy intentando hacer una sencilla extensión para chrome que muestre la url de la web que estoy viendo.

Pero por más modificaciones que realizo solo consigo que me muestre la url del archivo que donde se ejecuta el script. Es decir que al hacer clic sobre el icono de la extesión me muestra :

- "chrome-extension://dppmpeecpcbdkfkemiokpnaidghlhefe/ver_url.html"

En lugar de la url de la web que estoy viendo.

Os dejo código que estoy usando (más simple imposible) y que no funciona por si me podéis orientar.

```
URL = window.parent.location.href;
alert(URL)
```

Ya he probado con :

- window.location;
- window.location.href
- window.location.pathname
- etc....

Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

¿Puedes probar con esto?

```
chrome.tabs.query({
    'active': true,
    'currentWindow': true
}, function(tabs) {
    var url = tabs[0].url;
    alert(url);
});
```

Ten en cuenta que para acceder a la URL tienes que declarar los **permisos** correspondientes. Aquí está toda la información sobre `chrome.tabs` https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs